# What is the last version of postgres with pgadmin 3?

Tags: postgresql, pgadmin

For some reason I cant get used to the pgadmin 4 in web version. I found it very slow. For thing I want do fast I rather have pgadmin 3 even if that mean work with previous version of postgres.

So what was the last version of postgres with pgadmin 3?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

While you may be *strongly discouraged* from continuing to use pgAdmin 3, there's nothing stopping you if you *really want to use it*. Below you will see pgAdmin 3 connected to a postgresql 12 instance.

[image: pgAdmin 3 connected to postgresql 12]

Note however, that you're very much doing this at your own risk, you're going to have to click through *a lot of error messages* when running in an unsupported setup like this.

Some pretty obvious in retrospect...

[image: computer says no. but does it mean it?]
[image: xlog is wal, wal is xlog]

Some just annoying...

[image: error spam]
[image: error error spam spam]
[image: error error error spam spam spam]

In general I find a lot of these errors stem from breaking-change updates to the system catalogs between 9.* and 10+. Whether or not they're deal breakers to using this configuration is left to you. If you *do* decide to press ahead and try to use this setup, there will be a lot of heartache (for example, pgAdmin 3 as provided just won't run on macOS Catalina, end of discussion).

Around these parts you will hear a lot of the "just use `psql`" line. I use `psql` and I love it. But sometimes it's nice to have a GUI. I use pgAdmin 4 and I have a love-hate relationship with it. The pgAdmin line has been "meta-stable" IMO for quite some time and I imagine it will remain so for all but the most power-users for at least a bit.

Answer (score 3):

https://vvs.ru/pg/index-en.html

As of now the latest version is PgAdmin III 1.27.1b
The pgAdmin 3 supports Postgres database versions from 8.1 to 13.
I installed it for DB ver. 12 and it looks like everything works fine.

Answer (score 2):

You can download source code from https://github.com/AbdulYadi/pgadmin3. It supports up to PostgreSQL 12.1.

Answer (score 1):

According to [the pgAdmin download page](https://www.pgadmin.org/download/), that would be 9.5.

Don't select your database version based on a client GUI. PostgreSQL 9.5 will go out of support in about a year. Start using `psql`, it is included with PostgreSQL and much more powerful.

If you insist on a GUI, have a look at [the Wiki page listing client tools](https://wiki.postgresql.org/wiki/PostgreSQL_Clients).

Comment: More than the GUI itself I have a problem with the performance https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/251035/why-pgadmin-run-slower-than-pgadmin3

Comment: What is `psql` isn't that the lenguaje or is the command line?

Comment: `psql` is the command line client.

Comment: @JuanCarlosOropeza: https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/app-psql.html

Comment: Sorry but working from command line is a step back. And I'm used to working with command line since DOS but the GUI give you too many tools. Which one you recommend. Effectively the problem in my case is pgadmin 4. I get same udpate speed on pgadmin3 (even with the errors) and psql.  @a_horse_with_no_name

Comment: Well, I tried to answer your question. I cannot recommend a GUI, since I never use any. Asking for tool recommendations is off-topic, for (as you see) that is a question of taste.

Comment: @JuanCarlosOropeza: the performance of the UPDATE is completely independent of the SQL client.

Comment: @LaurenzAlbe: to be fair: the majority of users (especially developers that don't work with the  database all the time) prefer a GUI client. It makes editing and running queries much simpler. I think the adoption and acceptance of Postgres could have been much in the past if the tooling around it was better (I personally think that neither pgAdmin 3 nor pgAdmin 4 matches the quality of Postgres. But - as you correctly stated - this is completely a matter of personal taste)

Comment: PGAdmin4 is not a very good replacement for PGAdmin3.  there are several problems with it.  Yet EnterpriseDB killed it.  a none web-based tool http://www.sql-workbench.eu/  is not bad.  psql is very useful when one knows what one wants to do.  But for reverse engineering and to get an overview of how a DB is laid out psql sucks.  As the Saying goes the right tool for the right job.

Answer (score 0):

FYI  Big SQL has maintained PGAdmin3 to version 10.9

https://www.bigsql.org/pgadmin3/

Answer (score 0):

Pretty much all the links suggested on this topic are dead in 2023.

This build of [pgadmin3 supports postgresql 15](https://github.com/levinsv/pgadmin3) (at the time of this writing)